# Some PHP extensions available only for root user

Tags: centos, php, command-line-interface, php7, php.ini

I have installed PHP 7.4 (from remi) on CentOS 8 since I need that version on CLI.

The issue is with extensions, when I check modules (`php -m`) as root user I for example have `redis` enabled there, but if I check the same thing with any other user it's missing.

I noticed that root user getting PHP stuff from `/etc`, but all other users are getting them from `/usr/local/php`.

I'm using some git hooks on that server, and all stuff I'm running there (composer, drush...) are run from cli as exact user (no root user).

How I can enable extensions for other users that don't have root privileges?

**UPDATE**

`php -v` with root user:

```
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2021 14:19:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

`php -v` with any other user:

```
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb 28 2021 20:54:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Clean /usr/local of a previous installation from sources.

Comment: Are you sure that when executing php as a regular user you're actually executing the exact same php version the root user executes?

Comment: @RemiCollet how I can do that and how it will help?

Comment: @BogdanStoica I updated question with the output of php -v.

Comment: check "which php", and delete found executable in /usr/local

Comment: @RemiCollet I did that and I'm getting `-bash: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory` for non-root users when try to use php

Comment: Cache issue, logout / logon again

Comment: @RemiCollet that's it, everything's good now...thank you very much